# Firebase database: how can I change value of list item?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I have such structure in my database:

```
User 1
  +- items
       +- 1
       |  |- question: some question
       |  |- answer: some answer
       |
       +- 2
          |- question: another question
```

I want to add answer to second item, but I don't have the id.
I'm trying to get items and it returns

> [null, {answer: some answer, question: some question}, {question: another question}]

But I can't get needed item without `answer` field and I can't get their ids.

I tried to use `equalTo`, but it didn't help.

```
// attempt 1
Query child = _databaseReference.child(item._user).child(db_items).equalTo(null, key: db_answer);
child.reference().once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
  print('snapshot: ${snapshot.value}');
});

// attempt 2
Query child = _databaseReference.child(item._user).child(db_items).equalTo(null, key: db_answer);
child.reference().child(db_question).once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
  print('snapshot: ${snapshot.value}');
});
```

First attempt returns the same output as I wrote above, second returns null

So, does anybody know how can I add `answer` field to second question?

P.S. I use Flutter, but I don't think it means a lot for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you are trying to add 'answer' to your second item.
I would have done it in this way:
First is to know the key beforehand, so that I can insert a child node in the second item. That way i can write something like:
myDBReference.child("items").child("key_known_beforehand").child("answer").setValue("this is the ansewr");

Or in case I didnt know the key, which seems like the problem here:
I would use Firebase Query. Something like..
myDBReference.child("items").orderByValue().startAt(starting_point_of_child_item).endAt(ending_point_of_child_item).child
This query would givve me the requred node and i would set value there.

"

```
Using startAt(), endAt(), and equalTo() allows you to choose arbitrary starting and ending points for your queries
```

To filter data, you can combine any of the limit or range methods with an order-by method when constructing a query.

```
Unlike the order-by methods, you can combine multiple limit or range functions. For example, you can combine the startAt() and endAt() methods to limit the results to a specified range of values.
```

"

Comment: As I wrote - I don't have a key, so first way is not for my case (or I need some way to get this key somehow). Regarding second way - could you explain how it can be used in my case? What parameters have to be send in these methods?

Comment: instead of explaining here, let me give a link to  a really nice tutorial that i use.
https://howtofirebase.com/collection-queries-with-firebase-b95a0193745d
Hope it helps.
Good luck !

Comment: Actually, I didn't find needed information about appropriate using of `orderByValue` with `startAt` and `endAt`. It would be nice if you added some explanation